# dkim mail servers using domain as selector

Tags: dns, opendkim

I have set up a mail server but when I send mail to gmail accounts I get

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@h2993269.stratoserver.net header.s=porifera.site header.b=NDzL8dZn;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@porifera.site designates 81.169.136.154 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@porifera.site;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=porifera.site
```

If I am understanding the output here correctly, the gmail server is looking for a dkim record with the domain h2993269.stratoserver.net with the selector porifera.site. This is backwards. h2993269.stratoserver.net is the hostname which I used as a selector because opendkim recommends doing so. The dns record looks like this:
[image: screenshot of dns record on hosting provider interface]

This dmarc tester I found says the record is set up correctly.
https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-checker/?dmarcdns%5Btype%5D=dkim&dmarcdns%5Bselector%5D=h2993269.stratoserver.net&dmarcdns%5Bdomain%5D=porifera.site

the dkim signature on the mail looks like:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple;
    d=h2993269.stratoserver.net; s=porifera.site; t=1670839153;
```

which also has the selector and domain reversed so there must be an issue in my opendkim config

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about laying it out in a stackoverflow question has a way of clarifying the mind. I realised it must be an issue in my opendkim config so I went back through it all and sure enough my Keytable had

```
selector._domainkey.domain selector:domain:/path/to/key
```

but it should have been

```
selector._domainkey.domain domain:selector:/path/to/key
```